# Strategy for exporting data from One Database to a Standard set of DB vendors

Tags: mysql, integration, database

I have an application using MySQl as the DBMS. But many of clients want the data to be updated on their existing database on a different DBMS. So, we had to export data from our DBMS to theirs on a scheduled basis. But, every client has their own DBMS.

What would be the best strategy to design a framework such that the data available in our DBMS can be exported to the client's DBMS. Each client would have a different DBMS.

PS: Sorry for not being elaborate. 
Say for example the client needs only couple of columns from our DBMS and updated into his DBMS which would be different for each clients. So, they may not necessarily have the same architecture, but we can design a framework with which most DBMS will work and may be others will work with minimum changes.

Comment: new data to be inserted everyday in clients db. Is that what you meant

Comment: Really depends on the features of the other databases. Do they all support the same features? or do you have to account for different functionality? Do the DBMS all support a common import method? Can you invest in third party data migration tools that work with all the DBMS's you have to deal with?

Comment: @Napster
Yes. Everyday or every few hours.

Answer (score 0):

If you can write some code on your client's server, then write a script on their server which would read from your db and insert into client's db. Make sure you can call this script from your server.